# помогите найти ошибку, не открывается окно. без ошибок

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть программа на русском языке png и кнопки, написал без self. Решил на английский написать параметр Self. Ошибки нет.

```
   from tkinter import *

#def change_language():                                                   #кнопка online
    #tk.withdraw()                                                   #скрытие окна выбора
class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self = Toplevel(tk)                                               #окно
        self.geometry("1290x900")                                         #геометрия окна
        self.title("English version")                                     #названия окна
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)                         #запрет на изменения окна
        self.image = PhotoImage(file="image/ingl.png")                    #экран англиский
        screen2 = Label(self, image=self.image)                             #Экран выбора режима и языка(англиский)
        screen2.grid(row=0, column=0)                                   #Экран выбора режима и языка(англиский)
        bl = Button(self,image = online, command = onlin2)                #кнопка онлаин (англиский)
        bl.place(x=450,y=500, width=200, height=100)                    #Размеры кнопки
        bl = Button(self,image = online, command = change_lang)                #кнопка онлаин (англиский)
        bl.place(x=250,y=200, width=200, height=100)                    #Размеры кнопки
if __name__ == "__Main__":
    self().mainloop()
```

Comment: Забыл сказать окно не открывается.

Comment: Вы создали класс Main, но не создали ни одного экземпляра из этого класса win = Main(). И прочитайте про self, оно не должно = чему-то.

Comment: `if __name__ == "__Main__":` - сравните с любым примером в интернете. Есть большая разница с большой буквы написать или с маленькой. У вас просто никогда не выполняется это условие. Но это самая маленькая из проблем в вашем коде)